# Sagepay v3.0 php integration demo not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, opayo

I am trying to upgrade from an earlier version of sagepay php integration to the new v3.0.  First step is to get the demo working.  I downloaded VspPHPkit from the site and installed it under localhost/sagepay on my Ubuntu development environment.

I have setup the MYSQL and have checked that the mod_rewrite on Apache is enabled.  All good.  I have also copied the htaccess file to my web root.

My problem is that when I load localhost/sagepay/demo, the page renders ok but the links to the Form Protocol example points to localhost/sagepay/demo/form.  This is not a directory which is in the installed example and neither is it specified in the htaccess as a redirect.

I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It turned out that I had version 7.0 of PHP active rather than version 5.6. Once I switched to 5.6, it all worked fine.